# Excel VBA - VBA script does not work on target sheet once I copy a value from another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following VBA script:

```
    Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xCount As Long
    Dim valueCell As Range
    Dim timeStampCell As Range
    Dim targetCell As Range
    Dim xVal As Long

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    '''''EDIT''''''

    Set targetCell = Range("G15")
    Set timeStampCell = Range("R2")
    Set valueCell = timeStampCell.Offset(0, 1)

    '''''''''''''''

    xCount = Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, valueCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row - 1

    If Target.Address = targetCell.Address Then
        valueCell.Offset(xCount, 0).Value = targetCell.Value
        timeStampCell.Offset(xCount, 0).Value = Date
    Else
        If valueCell.Offset(Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, valueCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row - 2, 0).Value <> targetCell.Value Then
        valueCell.Offset(xCount, 0).Value = targetCell.Value
        timeStampCell.Offset(xCount, 0).Value = Date
        End If
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

It works properly when I use it in the active sheet (Data).
Actually, the script checks if there is a change in the target value (the value is updated using formulas from other cells) and if the target value (G15) has been changed, then copy the new value in the first available row of the table.

The problem is that I need to move the table to another sheet. 
I used a formula which copies the value from G15 of the initial sheet to the cell E1 of the new sheet (MonthlyData) and I moved the VBA script from "Data" to "MonthlyData". I have modified the script as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xCount As Long
    Dim valueCell As Range
    Dim timeStampCell As Range
    Dim targetCell As Range
    Dim xVal As Long

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    '''''EDIT''''''

    Set targetCell = Sheets("MonthlyData").Range("E1")
    Set timeStampCell = Sheets("MonthlyData").Range("A2")
    Set valueCell = timeStampCell.Offset(0, 1)

    '''''''''''''''

    xCount = Cells(Sheets("MonthlyData").Rows.Count, valueCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row - 1

    If Target.Address = targetCell.Address Then
        valueCell.Offset(xCount, 0).Value = targetCell.Value
        timeStampCell.Offset(xCount, 0).Value = Date
    Else
        If valueCell.Offset(Cells(Sheets("MonthlyData").Rows.Count, valueCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row - 2, 0).Value <> targetCell.Value Then
        valueCell.Offset(xCount, 0).Value = targetCell.Value
        timeStampCell.Offset(xCount, 0).Value = Date
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

And now the problem... If I manually update the E1 cell to another value works perfect, if the value E1 change automatically changing a value from sheet (Data) the value E1 in MonthlyData being updated but the VBA script does not work and the value is not updated in the table...

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Worksheet_Change` event in MonthlyData sheet supposed not to fire as there is no change in that sheet. Only value of the cell is being changed.

It is better to wrap up the code for `Worksheet_Change`of "MonthlyData" in a sub procedure and call it from DATA sheet's `Worksheet_Change` event from within the `if` branch where G10 is found changed.

Or

Simply change MonthlyData Sheet's E1 Cell directly from with in `Worksheet_Change` event of DATA sheet by adding one line

```
Sheets("MonthlyData").Range("E1").Value= targetCell.Value
```

**EDIT**:I tried the firing of Sheet("MonthlyData") `Worksheet_Change` event with the  following code placed in Sheet("DATA") `Worksheet_Change` event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target = Sheets("DATA").Range("G10") Then
Sheets("MonthlyData").Range("E1").Value = Sheets("DATA").Range("G10").Value
End If
End Sub
```

It is successfully putting G10 *(I used G10 instead of G15)* value to E1 and firing of  Sheet("MonthlyData") `Worksheet_Change` event. it is again checked with your full code of MonthlyData Worksheet_Change event and found working.

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Hi Ahmed, thank you for help. I didn't manage to fix it with your suggestion... Can you please give me the second option that you have suggested as part of the script? I mean if you have tried and it worked if possible add here all the script with your correction...

Comment: Hi Ahmed, I have tried before this but it didn't solve my problem, the second sheet behaves with exactly same way as to use formula. With both ways, the value in E1 of the MonthlyData is updated but the VBA does not work in order to add a line at the end of the table. If I manually change the value in E1 does it...

Comment: In your question you told _'I moved the VBA script from "Data" to "MonthlyData"._. If you are still using using your full `Worksheet_Change` event in DATA. then just _delete `Application.EnableEvents = False`_. It may be preventing MonthlyData Change event from firing. Waiting for  your feedback..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add code Worksheet_Change event on Data sheet as well. I am using this as an example if Sheets("MonthlyData").Range("E1") is a formula that came from Sheets("Data").Range("A1")
Please add this code to Data sheet:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Range("A1") Then
        Sheets("MonthlyData").Range("E1").Formula = Sheets("MonthlyData").Range("E1").Formula
    End If

End Sub
```

Hope this help.

Thanks.